# Linux kernel variables ending in 'i' meaning

Tags: linux-kernel

It's a random and stupid question, but I have no clue what the i stands for in structs with members like:

`[starting character]i_[some specifier]`

Examples are like: [bio struct](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17.2/source/include/linux/blk_types.h#L237), [everytime dm_target is referenced](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17.2/A/ident/dm_target), [bvec_iter](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17.2/source/include/linux/bvec.h#L38).

Whenever I read such a variable I read the complete name in my head, and it's very frustrating to me that I can't do it with these.

Comment: Well `bi_` is just short for `bvec_iter_`, same goes for `bi_o_struct` whose fields are `bi_...`. Not sure about `dm_target` though.

Comment: Oh okay, so not really any special meaning. Is there a reason why the `bio struct` fields aren't called `bio_...` instead of `bi_...`?

Comment: Just convention IMO, if you take a look you usually always have two letters to identify the struct they are fields of and then the real name. E.G. `struct timeval` has `tv_`, `struct timespec` has `ts_`, `struct sockaddr` has `sa_` and so on. Having longer prefixes could be too much of an hassle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There no meaning in `i_`, it's not special.

A loooong time ago structure members shared the same namespace as variables and such, they had to be unique - some people are used to that. And it is subjectively nice to have structure members starting with a unique prefix - IDE autocompletion works better, and it's easier to do lookup.

In the case of `struct bio` members, `bi_` is just a shortcut for... `bio_`.

In the case of `struct dm_target *ti` variable name, `ti` looks like a nice shorter form of `this` used in C++ and Python for referencing the current object.

In the case of `struct bvec_iter`, `bi_` is just a shorthand of `bvec_iter`. Above, you have `struct bio_vec` that uses `bv_` for struct members.

These are just conventions that a specific developer used to mark some abstractions in their source code. It has no specific meaning.

It's also easier to look sometimes - when I see `iter->bi_stuff`, I can "suspect" that `iter` is a pointer to something `bi` related (`bio`? `bvec_iter`?). In the context of many, many variables, such small clues are nice for the eye.

This all is subjective. It is *way* more important to follow one convention, rather that what convention it is.